# Django: URL namespacing with hyperlink

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have the url:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))
```

I created a hyperlink signup, I would like to direct the user to `"/accounts/signup/"`. When I don't put in a namespace I get an error that the namespace "accounts" doesn't exist when I put the url : `{% url accounts:account_signup%}` as the hyperlink. When I do put `namespace="accounts"` in, I get a `NoReverseMatch` error when I simply try to even access the url by typing it in the url bar.

Why am I not able to just name the above url (`name="accounts"`), while a url in allauths has the name `"account_signup"` and just write `{% url accounts:account_signup%}` as the link? I don't understand why with include I am forced to have namespace when I am not using duplicate names anywhere in the app. In addition, I don't understand why I get the `NoReverseMatch` error.

Comment: I guess django-allauth doesn't work if you use namespaces: it uses its own urls without a namespace, so if you use one, it can't find those urls anymore.

Comment: @knbk so I guess that means I have to hard code the link in ?. All allauths urls  have names.

Comment: No, it means you must use only the _name_, without a _namespace_. Use `{% url 'account_signup' %}` (which is just the name) instead of `{% url 'accounts:account_signup' %}` (which is a namespace followed by a name).

Answer (score 0):

You should try Like this

In your Project urls.py,you should provide the namespace as,

```
 url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls',namespace="accounts"))
```

In your project's app urls.py you should provide the "name" argument for the urls that is using this type of syntax for calling url's

```
action = {% url accounts:account_signup%}  //this is the action attribute of form tag

the url should be 

url(r'^account_signup/$',views.methodname,name='account_signup')
```

By giving this type of urls with the Name argument in url you will not getting "NO REVERSE MATCH FOUND ERROR"

or else you can directly give the url for the page you want to redirect,like below mentioned, in the form tag of html

```
action="/accounts/create_estimate/"   //this is the action attribute of form tag
```

You don't need to provide the Name argument for giving directly the url in action attribute of form tag